# Fading background image from normal image to faded image

Tags: android, android-layout

I am doing a project in which i want to fade my background image from normal to fade the same image so the text over it can be displayed properly...but i am not getting how to do it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting both images in a `TransitionDrawable`.  This is a type of drawable that is used to cross-fade between its layers when `startTransition(int)` is called.  See the `TransitionDrawable` documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html).